# find record combobox wizard does not list all fields

Tags: ms-access, combobox, find, ms-access-2010

In MS Access 2010 which has an ODBS link to a SQL Server 2008, I have created a form. The recordset of this form is all the records in a table called Individuals. I want to make a find record combobox using the combobox wizard. No biggie, right? Except for some reason the combobox wizard does not list all of the fields of the table, namely the fields I am interested in. The only fields available are numeric fields whereas the absent ones are varchar(max) fields.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe varchar(max) is equivalent to the Access memo type. These cannot be displayed in a combobox. You can manually create the combo selecting only Left(Field,255) characters for the varchar(max) fields.

Comment: This also happens for any varchar() field which is longer than 255 (not just max)